# Как спомощью date-fns получить время гринвича и прибавить к нему время секундах UTC, или отнять если UTC со знаком минус?

Tags: javascript, дата, date-fns

Нужно используя библиотеку date-fns получить значение времени в регионе. Имя региона не известно. Есть только значение timezone, которая хранит в себе секунды смещение от гринвича, оно может как отрицательное, так и положительное, например +3600 или -3600.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const utcDate = utcToZonedTime(new Date(), 'Africa/Dakar');

  console.log('--------->utcDate', utcDate);

  const dateInCity = add(utcDate, {
    seconds: weathers.current.timezone,
  });

  console.log('<<><dateInCity', dateInCity);

  const date = format(dateInCity, 'EEEEEE kk:mm dd MMM', { locale: ru });
```

Пока что так. 'Africa/Dakar' имеет время 0 gmt, то есть время без смещения от гринвича